# ror project ajax load google map issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I need to use google map service in my ror(ruby on rails)project.However i facing some problems. as we know. we need to include this header to application.html.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE"></script>
<%= link_to 'ajax', boys_ajax_path(:format=>:js), :remote=>true %><div id='ajax' style='width:300px;height:300px;border:1px solid gray'></div>
```

ajax.js.erb code

```
$("#ajax").html("<div style='width:100%;height:100%;border:1px solid gray' id='allmaps'></div>")
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("allmaps"), {
            zoom: 15, 
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.3, 120.6), 
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            panControl: false, 
            scaleControl: false, 
            mapTypeControl: false, 
            streetViewControl:false,
            zoomControl: true, 
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
            }
        });
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map, position: map.getCenter() });
```

When i first click the ajax button. the google map load success. however when i click twice time. the google map does load. what'wrong with google map. Maybe we should submit google map key every time when we click the ajax button.
   Is there any method to solve my problem. send google map key every time when ajax action happen..

Answer (score 0):

There is one gem called gmaps4rails go for it. [here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails)

Comment: thx Pinak Thakkar. is there any other methods except this one

Comment: else need to send google map key every time when ajax action happen